# Visual Studio New Line Curly Brace Formatting Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-formatting

My problem is when I create a new method it looks like this...

```
public string firstName {
}
```

The cursor is stays right before the }, and then if I type more code it looks like...

```
public string firstName {
    get;}
```

And...

```
public string firstName {
    get;
    set;}
```

Then I have to press enter for it to look like...

```
public string firstName {
    get;
    set;
}
```

What I want for it to look like from the beginning is...

```
public string firstName {
    <cursor here>
}
```

I've looked all over in the formatting options, and can't seem to find anything. I used to get it like this before, and I don't know what happened that caused this issue. It's very annoying! Please help.

Comment: What version of VS are you using? That might help people figure out the right option.

Comment: I'm using the latest update of the community Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Wait, I’ve always just typed one brace, hit the right arrow, and hit enter, and it’s always where I need it to be…

Answer (score 10):

Try this. Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->New Lines. In there, under New line options for braces, make sure those are all checked. That's what determines where the braces go when you type the left brace and then hit enter.

**edit**: That didn't do it, but second suggestion of Wrapping then checking "Leave block on single line" did do it for OP.

Comment: I've already tried that and it causes the same problem except the opening brace is on a new line and the closing brace is on the next line. There is no empty line between the two. This problem is happening on both my laptop and desktop, and it didn't happen before.

Comment: @Nasir Maybe Wrapping -> Leave block on single line? Mine is checked. My VS does what you want yours to do. Other than that, maybe gnomes in your computers?

Comment: @Nasir You've very welcome. Please upvote/accept since it worked. I'll edit my answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022,
Try to disable some or all checkboxs at:

**Tools > Options (CTRL + ,) > C# (or another language) > Code Style > Formatting > New Lines**

But, if the problem is the cursor behind the close braces, I solved it by check *Leave block on single line* and *Leave statements and member declarations on the same line* at:

**Tools > Options (CTRL + ,) > C# (or another language) > Code Style > Formatting > Wrapping**

Maybe other version of Visual Studio have different settings location, You could explore it.

I hope that helps :)