# Visual Studio Mac doesn't put the cursor on a new line after typing an open curly brace followed by "return" in C# since last update

Tags: c#, newline, visual-studio-mac, curly-braces, autoformat

Since the last Update it looks like this, when I hit "return" after the curly brace:

```
private void MyMethod() {
|<cursor is here>}
```

What it looked like and I want it to look like is this:

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    |<cursor is here>
}
```

The suggested solution in this post doesn't work for me:
[Visual Studio New Line Curly Brace Formatting Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817509/visual-studio-new-line-curly-brace-formatting-issue)

I think I know the related settings, but I tried like almost every combination without success:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just to be sure: Are you running any addons (e.g. Resharper) that could interfere with this?

Comment: I don't have/use any addons.

Comment: This is a bug which will be fixed in Visual Studio for Mac 17.6.1. The order of the handlers in the editor do not have an exact ordering in earlier versions of Visual Studio for Mac and that can affect how the brace handler works. Restarting Visual Studio for Mac can sometimes fix this. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Braces-are-not-going-to-new-line/10398018