# How do I change the way my brace completion is handled in Visual Studio 2022 for Unity when coding in HLSL?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, formatting, hlsl, curly-braces

[Screenshot of brace completion and matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vKYu.png)

I'm trying to learn how to code using HLSL in Unity and the first immediate hurdle has been the fact that the auto-complete brace matching puts the curly parentheses in different indentations. In the image provided above, you can see that the last brace supposedly lines up with the indentation of the int Method, however it actually connects to the Shader.

Below is the formatting that I am far more familiar with and find considerably more intuitive:

[Screenshot of preferred brace completion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uw3n.png)

I found an extension called "HLSL Tools for Visual Studio" by Tim Jones, however it doesn't seem to change anything at all.
I have also looked in "Tools > Options > Text Editor > HLSL > Formatting" and messed around with a bunch of different setting there with no different results.

[Screenshot of formatting settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dCHE.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio New Line Curly Brace Formatting Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817509/visual-studio-new-line-curly-brace-formatting-issue)